# SeeedDuino/Grove and the story of not being able to upload programs

Tags: uploading, bootloader

I am new to the arduino world and wanted to start playing with the micro controllers, I am a .NET developer by trade so not completely new to this kind of world.

I purchased a seeedduino v3 and a Grove started kit (No soldering skills here) and can't even get the basics to work.

I am setting up a simple button to light up the LED program. I have had it run once or twice but it seems really hit or miss on whether or not the Arduino IDE actually gets the program onto the seeedduino.

***Arduino IDE (1.5.6-r2) set-up:***
Followed setup instructions found here: [SeeedDuino v3](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Seeeduino_v3.0#How_do_I_configure_the_Arduino_IDE.3F)

- Board: Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila
- Processor: ATmega328
- Port: COM4 [this is what popped up once device was plugged in]
- Button is installed on D3
- LED is installed on D7

***Program:***

```
int button = 3;
int LED = 7;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(button, INPUT); //define button on INPUT devices
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);   //define LED on OUTPUT device
}

void loop() 
{
  int buttonState = digitalRead(button); //read the status of hte button

  if(buttonState == HIGH) //also used (buttonState == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH); //also used digitalWrite(LED, 1)  
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW); //also used digitalWrite(LED, 0)
  }
}
```

Upload Verbose Message:

```
avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1070 bytes of flash verified
avrdude: Send: Q [51]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I have only had the LED from this program turn on twice, then reloading it ruins it.

***SIDE NOTE***

If I try and run Burn BootLoader I get this message-

```
avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : stk500v2
avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"
```

Comment: You had a USB-problem too: 'avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"'. Always verify if your device actually got the port assigned you expect it to have assigned. Not sure if you can assign a device a static COM-port on Windows, I know it is possible on Linux.

Comment: Yeah I had ended up forcing it to be COM251 to be consistent. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK mystery solved!

I ended up getting [Visual Micro Debugger](http://www.visualmicro.com/) plug-in for my Visual Studio 2013 since I am native .NET programmer. I could see that the code was indeed loaded onto the board and when I pressed the button it was indeed getting to the line of code for setting the digital LED to HIGH.

It was a very unfortunate case of trying different components and learning I actually had 3 dead LEDs and one bad cable. After getting functioning ones it's all good. :) unlucky me just had 4 bad parts in my kit.

Output from Visual Studio Debugging:

```
Legend:
line 12 = button state check
line 16 = button pressed turn on LED
line 20 = button not pressed turn off LED

=================OUTPUT====================
14:01:04.372 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 12  loop() 
14:01:04.372 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 16  loop() 
14:01:04.481 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 10
14:01:04.481 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 12  loop()
14:01:04.592 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 16  loop()
14:01:04.592 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 10
14:01:04.696 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 12  loop()
14:01:04.697 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 20  loop()
14:01:04.804 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 10
14:01:04.804 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 12  loop()
14:01:04.912 SeeedDuinoPlayground.ino, line 20  loop()
```